VBA: Using two existing values to create an intersection
I have two separate tables, one containing the location information and current quarter in a fixed position.



LocationB
Quarter1



I would like to run a macro, which takes the above mentioned information and marks the intersecting cell with a value in a different worksheet.



Location
Quarter1
Quarter2
Quarter3
Quarter4




LocationA
--------
--------
--------
--------


LocationB
Green
--------
--------
--------


Locationc
--------
--------
--------
--------



My idea is to use match to determine the correct row and column number and then just insert a value there.
However, I struggle to use match correctly.
The lookup value is on the current worksheet, while the accompanying array to find the row number is on the adjacent worksheet.
Sub Test()

Dim wsUB As Worksheet
Dim UBLocation As Variant

Set wsUB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Übersichtsblatt")

UBLocation = Application.Match(Cells(6, 3), wsUB.Range("A1:A35"), 0)


End Sub

I get the error code 2042
Many thanks for any suggestions or advice.

Does the value in C6 really match a value in Range("A1:A35")? Check for invisible characters, eg trailing blanks

This error is the #N/A error means not avail. That means that no match was found in the given range.

I would recommend using ADO/SQL for this problem, especially if you have much
records to be updated from the other sheet.
Sub Test()
    Dim adoCN As Object, TargetFile As String, strSQL As String
    Dim UBLoc As String, UBQuarter As String
    
    UBLoc = Sheets("Arbeitsblatt").Range("C6")
    UBQuarter = Sheets("Arbeitsblatt").Range("E6")
   
    Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    TargetFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
    adoCN.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    adoCN.Properties("Data Source") = TargetFile
    adoCN.Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes"
    adoCN.Open
        
    strSQL = " Update [Übersichtsblatt$] As T1 " & _
             " Set T1.[Quarter1] = '" & UBQuarter & "'" & _
             " Where T1.[Location]= '" & UBLoc & "'"
   
    adoCN.Execute (strSQL)
    
    adoCN.Close
    Set adoCN = Nothing
End Sub


It seems that I had to set the lookup value as a separate variable to function properly. I've attached the rest of the code for everyone if they have some recommendations.
Sub Test()

Dim wsUB As Worksheet
Dim UBLocation As Variant, UBQuarter As Variant
Dim UBLoc As Variant, UBQ As Variant
Dim rngUB As Range

Set wsUB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Übersichtsblatt")
Set UBLoc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arbeitsblatt").Range("C6")
Set UBQ = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arbeitsblatt").Range("E6")

UBLocation = Application.Match(UBLoc, wsUB.Range("A1:A35"), 0)
UBQuarter = Application.Match(UBQ, wsUB.Range("A1:E1"), 0)

Set rngUB = wsUB.Cells(UBLocation, UBQuarter)

rngUB.Value = "Green"

End Sub

